# Number of non-shortest paths

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

In the figure below, the small square is all the unit square. how many paths which have length 7 from the point $A$ to $B$? Can we solve this problem in general?

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question to show what you have attempted and explain where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig  I tried to use the adjacency matrix. But it seems to be an inefficient way...

Comment: What is wrong with the adjacency matrix approach? I just typed the matrix into my computer, raised it to the $7$th power, and saw that the answer is 133. It only took me two minutes.

Comment: @Nick If we can use a computer, you are definitely right. I just want to know how to solve it more combinatorically and without using a computer.

Comment: Maybe you can find a recursive/inductive formula for how many paths based on the size of the rectangle, based on the count for smaller rectangles? Then work your way up from the 1-by-1 square.

Comment: In this case, you either have four rightward moves, one leftward move (which must follow the first rightward move and precede the fourth one), and two upward moves or have three upward moves, one downward move (which must follow the first upward move and precede the third one), and three rightward moves.